# How to capture which module that prints to stdout/stderr within the whole python application?

Tags: python, logging

I have a python web app that has global logger definition. Both stderr and stdout are overloaded to pass their string buffer to logging. However when there is an output from stdout/stderr, it only prints the logger module (in my formatter i added the module name), not the module where its coming from.

Is it possible to capture which modules those outputs are coming from? If so, how?

edit: added code here

```
class RedirectToLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, output,logger):
        self.logger = logger
        self.flush = output.flush
    def write(self, line_buffer):
        for line in line_buffer.rstrip().splitlines():
            self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())
# this will invoke stderr/stdout output to logger.
sys.stdout = RedirectToLogger(sys.stdout, app_logger)
sys.stderr = RedirectToLogger(sys.stderr, app_logger)
```

Comment: That depends on how the standard outputs are redirected to logging. It would help your question if you could add that information.

Comment: So basically, i configure logger and then I create an object to overload stdout/stderr, something like this:
```python
class RedirectToLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, output,logger):
        self.logger = logger
        self.flush = output.flush

    def write(self, line_buffer):
        for line in line_buffer.rstrip().splitlines():
            self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())
sys.stdout = RedirectToLogger(sys.stdout, app_logger)
sys.stderr = RedirectToLogger(sys.stderr, app_logger)


# this will invoke stderr/stdout output logger.
```
edit: added code

Comment: It would be best to edit that code into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer from blues seems to be a neat solution for version >3.8
For me, this was what I needed:

```
sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_filename
```

`_getframe()` argument 1 will grab the frame object before the logger from the stack, which is the file where stdout/stderr is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Requires Python 3.8 or later:

With the information given in a comment this is possible to solve: when your redirect calls the `log()` method you can tell it that the caller can be found by going back one extra frame in the callstack. The `stacklevel` kwarg is used for that.

```
self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip(), stacklevel=2)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to support that `stacklevel` argument.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d999cbf4adea053be6dbb612b9844635c4dfb8e/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1702

Comment: @Ritsard it was added here: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/dde9fdbe453925279ac3d2a6a72102f6f9ef247c You need a more recent version of python. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ahh makes sense, my system runs 3.6.